# Python: Passing arguments to wsgi function in module

Tags: python, wsgi

So... this is what I can't get done.

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/plain'),
              ('Content-Length', str(len(response_body)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [I WANT THIS TO BE PASSED TO THE FUNC AS AN ARGUMENT]
```

How do I do this?
Can I Pass this as an argument or does the wsgi application function only take 2?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: made it clearer

Comment: It will be passed once you run it, I'm not sure what your problem is.

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of middleware that post-processes the response?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear:
"TO BE PASSED TO THE FUNC AS AN ARGUMENT"
Which function are you talking about?

Take a look at Werkzeug library, I think you will find it easy to use:
http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/